# iPhone APP Submission Restricting Hardware With Microphone

Tags: iphone, microphone, submission

We have an app that we would like to restrict to only devices with Microphones.  We added this into the Plist and now can not submit the app since we have already submitted the app without the restriction.  What is the deal with this, any easy way around this?

Also, Is there a way to restrict installation on the iPad / iTouch while allowing installations on iPad?  Is there a Plist entry for this?  The only real item the sticks out is the IOS Version.

Also what about devices that can have Microphones plugged in but not imbedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do the submission with the microphone restriction would be to create a completely new app in the appstore, and just change the bundle identifier of your local Xcode project. Apple can't complain that it used to not be restricted in this manner when it's an entirely new app.

You can handle both external and internal microphones with [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1). A more high-level implementation is [`AVAudioRecorder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW7).

Comment: Yes, we have seen that we can't make anything "more restrictive" then the first submission.........

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with your first query but you can compile only for iPad by specifying iPad & not iPhone/iPad in the target devices part of the project's settings in Xcode.